# Entity Framework mapping to existing FoxPro free tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping, foxpro

I am working with a pre-existing set of FoxPro tables.  One table in specific

```
public class Charges
{
    public string Bill_Num { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Chargeid { get; set; }
    public string Postid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Createdt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modifydt { get; set; }
    public string Createtm { get; set; }
    public string Modifytm { get; set; }
{
```

seems to be TPH.  The discriminator is the `Type` field (`C` or `P`), so I am mapping along these lines:

```
public abstract class LineItem
{
    public string Bill_num { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Createdt { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modifydt { get; set; }
    public string Createtm { get; set; }
    public string Modifytm { get; set; }
}

public class LineItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<LineItem>
{
    public LineItemMap()
    {
        this.Map<Charge>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("C"));
        this.Map<Posting>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("P"));

        this.ToTable("Charges");
        this.Property(t => t.Bill_Num).HasColumnName("Bill_Num");
        this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");
        this.Property(t => t.Createdt).HasColumnName("Createdt");
        this.Property(t => t.Modifydt).HasColumnName("Modifydt");
        this.Property(t => t.Createtm).HasColumnName("Createtm");
        this.Property(t => t.Modifytm).HasColumnName("Modifytm");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Charge : LineItem
{
    public string Chargeid { get; set; }
}

public class ChargeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Charge>
{
    public ChargeMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Chargeid);

        this.Property(t => t.Chargeid)

        this.ToTable("Charges");
        this.Property(t => t.Chargeid).HasColumnName("Chargeid");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Posting : LineItem
{
    public string Postid { get; set; }
}

public class PostingMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Posting>
{
    public PostingMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Postid);

        this.Property(t => t.Postid)

        this.ToTable("Charges");
        this.Property(t => t.Postid).HasColumnName("Postid");
    }
}
```

If I do this, `LineItem` is missing a simple primary key.  I think a composite key of `{ t.Bill_num, t.Createdt, t.Createtm }` would be unique, but I am not sure if EF and/or the FoxPro provider will like that.

The second problem is there seems to be a subclass of both `Charges` and `Postings` that encompasses voiding entries (aka deletes) and does not appear to be assigned a `Chargeid`/`Postid`, but it does have a discriminator so they will be derived types with a `null` or `" "` key value.

Am I missing something, or am I on the right track with my mappings/key assignments?

Comment: Check out this template, it creates the model and the Fluent api from an existing db, it saved me a lot of time and headaches. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838, I created a console application where I used it, then I just copied the code that was generated into my project.

Comment: Take a look at the VFP Entity Framework Provider project on CodePlex. Tom wrote a Blog article on VFP Free Tables  http://vfpefprovider.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Raphael I suspect the template will give me something similar to the EF Powertools reverse engineering function (which has been helpful in generating the basic objects) because I am reverse-engineering FoxPro tables (if I can even get it to work at all).  Going to give it a shot and see if it gives me anything more useful, but I am primarily looking for insight on how to map the POCOs I already have generated to provide relationships that aren't contained in the free tables.

Comment: @FrankPerez I actually already use VFP EF Provider to generate the POCOs I am currently using.  The Free Tables Code-First blog is actually how I know about the fluent API primary key trick to fix the lack of candidate key in the free tables, as well.  This question pertains to deriving POCO inheritance from the table (which contains no relational/inheritance information).